# What should I do if the const value is still 'changed' by inputting a value in C++?

Tags: c++, xcode

This is a small software for score statistics, which has two main variables: ppl and type, the latter represents the number of subjects to be counted.

However, when this program runs the inner loop for the second time, it will define ppl as the value entered by the user, even though ppl is a const value.

[ppl which was 'changed' by inputting a value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5gGG.png)

When I tried to change the array of grades to a string array, this problem disappeared. Although I can convert data forcedly, I wanna know what is the solution to this problem? Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    int input = 0;
    cout << "How many people do you want to enter grades for?" << endl;
    cin >> input;
    const int ppl = input;
    
    cout << flush;
    
    cout << "How many subject grades would you like to enter for these people?" << endl;
    cin >> input;
    const int type = input;
    
    int score[][type] = {};
    
    for (int i = 0; i < ppl; i++) {
        
        for (int j = 0; j < type; j++) {
            
            cout << "Please enter the number " << i + 1 << " person's number " << j + 1 << " score:" << endl;
            
            cin >> score[i][j];
            
            cout << "Successful!" << endl;
            
            // Debug
            cout << "ppl: " << ppl << ", type: " << type << endl;
            
        }
    }
    
    cout << "Results Statistics" << endl;
    
    for (int l = 0; l < ppl; l++) {
        cout << "Number " << l << ": ";
        
        for (int m = 0; m < type; m++) {
            cout << score[l][m] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Typo? `int score[][type]` instead of `int score[ppl][type]`? The chance of someone else having the same symptom for this undefined behavior seems small.

Comment: Seems like you are accessing uninitialized memory space, thus the unpredictable behaviour. Also my IDE raised a warning about `int score[][type]`, you should change it.

Comment: Thanks for replying. When I used `int score[ppl][type]`, Xcode showed an error: Variable-sized object may not be initialized, which was the reason that I didn't type 'ppl'.

Comment: @Rinsuki So you removed the dimension instead of removing the initialization? How do you expect `score` to have enough space allocated to it? You write to each `int` before you read the value, so initialization is not needed. You try to access `score[i]` for `i` between `0` and `ppl`, so the dimension **is** needed.

Answer (score 2):

```
    int score[][type] = {};
```

is bad. Variable-Length Array is not in the standard C++ and it has less elements than used, so out-of-range access will happen and some data may be broken.

Use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of that:

```
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > score(ppl, std::vector<int>(type));
```

Comment: I tried running the program and out-of-range was definitely possible.

Comment: Not just a VLA, but a zero-length array too: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/nGz1vcMrx

Comment: Thanks for replying! I will use `std::vector` next.